# Get value of object in different <li>

Tags: javascript, html

This code is working, the onclick event is able to send the parameters

```
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="someting1" onclick="somefunction(something1,something2.value);"><input type="calendar" id="something2">
</td>
```

but when I do it like this, the onclick event is unable to get the value of "someting2"

```
<tr>
<td>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="someting1" onclick="somefunction(something1,something2.value);">
        </li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="calendar" id="something2">
                </li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
</td>
```

i don't know how to call the value of the calendar type input in the second example, when i use the chrome debugger in the first example the values are sent fine to the actual function, 
    on the second example the "someting2.value" arrives empty to the function

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use or need a closing slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input>` tags are self-closing, so you don't need the `</input>` in there twice. You're also creating a second list without closing the first.

Here's your corrected code

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="someting1" onclick="somefunction(something1,something2);">
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="calendar" id="something2">
            </li>
         <ul>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope this helps

```
<input type="checkbox" id="someting1" onclick="somefunction(this);">

    <script type="text/javascript">
            function somefunction(e) {
                alert(e.checked);
            }
        </script>
```

There are some other mistakes i saw in this code snippet

1. No need of end input tag
   `<input type="checkbox" id="someting1" />` <- this is just enough
2. No end tags of `</tr>,</td>,</ul>`
   (you can see all the html errors in developer tools in new web browsers e.g chrome, firefox, IE7)

Answer (score 0):

There is no closing tag on input 1. The closing tag is in the second li.

Comment: `<input>` doesn't need closing tags.

Comment: It has to be like this <input type=“”/> with the forward slash at the end

Comment: No it doesn't. The slash is optional.

Answer (score 0):

input tag should be like this

```
<input type="calendar" id="something2">
```

not like this

```
<input type="calendar" id="something2"></input>
```

and at last you forget to close td and tr tag